# When authenticating a user with OAuth 2.0 how does the redirect URL know what user they belong to?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I'm new to web development and trying to get my feet wet by building a web app that uses Google APIs. I was reading Google's documentation on using OAuth 2.0, but the redirect URL bit has me a bit confused. According to the example [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#handlingtheresponse) a successful authentication will send a response to

```
{redirect_url}?state=/profile&code={auth_code}
```

The response URL doesn't specify a user and neither does the response load as far as I know. How does the redirect URL endpoint know which user is tied to the authorization code it just received?

There was a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577586/determine-user-id-in-oauth-callback), but the answers focus on passing query parameters to the redirect URL. I'm not trying to do that. I want to understand how the redirect endpoint associates an OAuth response to a particular user. Note that I'm pretty new to all of this, so my confusion might stem from not understanding how HTTPS calls work or something similar.

Comment: The authentication server has the authentication code stored it knows what user it was that clicked accept.  redirect url has nothing to do with that, all that does is tell the authentication server where to send the authentication code.

Comment: I get how this works on Google's OAuth servers. I meant how does *my* service know which user the authentication code belongs to? Say I have two users on my web app. Suddenly my redirect URL receives a response with an auth code. How do I know if the response is part of the auth flow for user A or user B?

Comment: I use a session var in PHP when its returned to the users browser it knows who it was. What language are you using?  That was a good comment made me think there for a minute :)

Comment: Agreed with Dalm. Session will work here.

Comment: I am using C# for this

Answer (score 2):

A notable detail is when your redirect URL receives a response with code, it is the Google authorization server that **redirect user's browser to your server**. So it's user's browser that send a request to your server with code.

In other word, actually, you question is: "When your server receives many requests from many users, how do you know which user a request comes from"

I think you need to learn something about [session or cookie](http://www.f5.com/pdf/white-papers/cookies-sessions-persistence-wp.pdf) which allows 
HTTP to become stateful.