# How do I know which user authorized access when the authorization server redirects the browser back to the redirect url

Tags: oauth-2.0

I'm working on a Java Web Application and I have a question regarding OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow as it is described [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2):

> This flow is implemented using GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow. The steps
>   are:
>
> - End-user logs in to your application. You will need to associate
>     that user with a user ID that is unique for your application.
> - Call AuthorizationCodeFlow.loadCredential(String) based on the user ID to
>     check if the end-user's credentials are already known. If so, we're
>     done.
> - If not, call AuthorizationCodeFlow.newAuthorizationUrl() and
>     direct the end-user's browser to an authorization page to grant your
>     application access to their protected data.
> - The Google authorization
>     server will then redirect the browser back to the redirect URL
>     specified by your application, along with a code query parameter. Use
>     the code parameter to request an access token using
>     AuthorizationCodeFlow.newTokenRequest(String).
> - Use AuthorizationCodeFlow.createAndStoreCredential(TokenResponse, String)
>     to store and obtain a credential for accessing protected resources.

Regarding the last 2 steps my question is:

How do I know which user authorized access when the authorization server redirects the browser back to the redirect url? All I get is a code query parameter which contains the authorization code.

Can the state parameter be used for that? I've read that it should be used to prevent cross-site request forgery which is another purpose. Is it ok to use state parameter to get the relation?

And yes, I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989290/when-authenticating-a-user-with-oauth-2-0-how-does-the-redirect-url-know-what-us) but I don't know if the session-solution works in my scenario since I only have rest services.